# Word guessing game - problem with picking random word every time the loop runs

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, random

I want to get a new word choice every time I answer one word but I'm facing issue with getting a new random word from the word list even after using `random.shuffle()`.

My answer:

1. Create a dictionary (keys, values) of german words by extracting from csv file where keys will be in german, values in english
2. You want to display a random value from the dict and ask the user to enter the meaning

   ```
   import csv
   import random
   play_game = input(' Press \'y\' for yes and \'n\' for no')
   while play_game == 'y':
       with open('/Users/pydev97/Desktop/wordlist.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
           csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
           for row in csv_reader:
               keys = row['MEANING']
               values = row['WORDS']
               new_dict = dict({keys : values})

       keys_list = list(new_dict.keys()) # converting dict values to a list
       random.shuffle(keys_list)
       for word in keys_list:
         display = '{}'
         print(display.format(word))
         user_answer = input('Answer : ')

         if user_answer == new_dict[word]:
            print('You got it right')
         else:
            print('You got it wrong')
   ```

Output I'm getting:

```
Press 'y' for yes and 'n' for noy
to participate
Answer : dd
You got it wrong
to participate
Answer : es
You got it wrong
to participate
Answer : mit machen/teil nehmen
You got it right
to participate
Answer :
```

Comment: `I'm facing issue with getting a new random word from the word list` please explain this issue rather than just saying you have it.

Comment: There is only one entry in your dictionary. You recreate `new_dict` in every loop.

Comment: @RandomDavis so what I meant is as you can see in the code I have used the random.shuffle command to shuffle my list and thus get me a new word every time I answer the question. But somehow the same word keeps getting asked again and again and its not getting shuffled. I would like new words to be asked after every answer.

Comment: Maybe you can post an [mre]? That way we could just paste in your code, run it, and see the same issue as you.

Comment: @RandomDavis okay so I did try the minimal reproducible example and surprisingly it works! I created a small dict as seen below and eveytime I answer a new word gets asked. But why am I not able to get the same output with my csv file imported? Any problems in that?

Comment: 'import random
word_dict = {'dog' : 'der Hund', 'cat' : 'die Katze', 'book' : 'das Buch', 'pen' : 'der Kuli'}
keys_list = list(word_dict.keys())
random.shuffle(keys_list)
for word in keys_list:
    display = '{}'
    print(display.format(word))
    user_answer = input('Answer : ')
        
    if user_answer == word_dict[word]:
        print('You got it right')
    else:
        print('You got it wrong')'

Comment: @AdithKrishnan all code must go in your question, not in a comment, since comments can't show indentation or proper formatting. You should edit that example into your post. Also it's not actually a minimal reproducible example if you can't reproduce the issue. Also did you at any point step through your code in an IDE debugger? If not you absolutely should do that ASAP since it'll probably quickly reveal the real problem.

Comment: @RandomDavis so sorry this is my first time using stack overflow.. struggling a bit with how things work! But on the brighter side I just got the output, it works! Thanks again for your timely inputs!

Comment: @martineau thanks much for the rearrangement and formatting!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
   import csv
   import random
   play_game = input(' Press \'y\' for yes and \'n\' for no')
   with open('/Users/pydev97/Desktop/wordlist.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
       new_dict={}
       csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
       for row in csv_reader:
           keys = row['MEANING']
           values = row['WORDS']
           new_dict[keys] = values     
           keys_list = list(new_dict.keys()) # converting dict values to a list
   while play_game == 'y':
       random.shuffle(keys_list)
       for word in keys_list:
         display = '{}'
         print(display.format(word))
         user_answer = input('Answer : ')
   
         if user_answer == new_dict[word]:
            print('You got it right')
         else:
            print('You got it wrong')
       play_game = input(' Press \'y\' for yes and \'n\' for no')
```

Answer (score 0):

This line just sets new_dict to the latest key:value pair

```
new_dict = dict({keys : values})
```

whereas you probably want to append to that growing new_dict.

```
new_dict[keys] = values
```

Comment: where do I add that line you said?

Comment: Just after values = row['WORDS']

Comment: And of course you will have to create an empty dictionary before the loop.

Comment: Or, you could move the csv reading part before the game loop. Doesn't look like that should have to be re-read with every new game, unless you want to allow changes to the csv file in-game.

Comment: @GeraldChu tried it doesn't seem to be working :/ getting the same result of the same word being asked again and again instead of being shuffled..

Comment: And where to you create the empty dictionary?